# Sorting contents of local Querysnapshot document by a field

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method that fetches data from databse i.e. Firestore.

The main values in database are

```
category : "remote"
postTime : "2021-01-16 13:58:58.183760"
summary : "This is the summary text"
```

Once I have obtained a SnapShot copy locally I am sorting it like following for use in the app;

```
  subCategoryQuery() async {

    final filteredDocs = await localCopy.docs
        .where((element) => element.data()["category"] == "Remote")
        .toList();

    return filteredDocs;
  }
```

This is giving me the desired output i.e. where category is marked as "remote". However there is another field called `"postTime"` which is a time stamp. **How do I further filter this to sort in descending order?!**

Comment: Can you add how the example element looks like?

Comment: @vitooh I have updated the question. The field I am trying to sort with is actually a timestamp.